# heroku-postgresql update broke my app, can I revert autorelease so that data in db stored before the release is saved?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, postgresql-12

When running `heroku releases` I see the following information:

| version | description | ldap | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v364 | Update HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER by heroku-postgresql | heroku-postgresql@addons.heroku.com | 2021/01/13 17:09:43 -0800 |
| v363 | Enable allow-multiple-sni-endpoints feature | api-maintenance@heroku.com | 2020/08/06 11:20:42 -0700 |
| v362 | Update HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TEAL by heroku-postgresql | heroku-postgresql@addons.heroku.com | 2019/10/16 19:54:44 -0700 |

[image]

The latest **Heroku** auto release has broken my legacy app as it changed PostgreSQL version from `9.6` to `12.5` that is not currently supported by the app.

I wonder if I can rollback this auto change done on 2021/01/13 (v364) ?

Another question is if I am going to use Heroku standard rollback command `heroku rollback v363` will all data stored b/w v363 and v364 releases (2019/10/16 - 2020/08/06) be saved after rollback?

And last question, will the data created after v364 release (2021/01/13 - now) remain untouched after rollback to release v363?

Comment: Did you figure out what to do here? I had the same issue for some apps I made last year that I hadn't checked on in a while. All totally broken now

Comment: Yes, check my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by going long path:

1. I set up virtual machine, VirtualBox worked fine for me. I setup different versions of Postgres, both 9 and 12 on VM
2. I exported DB from Heroku and converted from 12 to 9 on my local VM. First I loaded DB backup using Heroku Web UI. I imported DB file to my local Postgres 12, then exported db into SQL text file. Then I re-imported data from SQL text form to Postgres 9
3. My app needed to support legacy stack, Ruby version was quite old and no longer supported by Heroku. Also the app with legacy Ruby version was tested with Ubuntu 14, and Heroku stopped supporting that OS. So I setup Docker Container on AWS that is using Ubuntu 14,  etc and deployed the app to container and Postgres DB 9, setup in AWS RDS

[Here](https://dev.to/farleyknight/how-to-deploy-a-rails-application-to-aws-with-docker-2fnc) you can find nice article how to create Docker Container running Ruby app on AWS. I followed steps mentioned there and that worked for me.